# Return data only without field name in Sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize ORM to fetch data from db

```
.findAll({
    attributes: ['value'],
    where: {
        code: { [Op.like]: 'images_default_droplet_%' },
        is_published: 1
    }
})
```

and it return like this:

```
{"value":"data"}
```

can I just get the data only without the field name?

return that I want like this:

```
{"data"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `{"data"}` isn't a valid JSON structure. You could convert it to an array of "datas" using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map); passing `raw: true` to `findAll()` will return an array of plain JSON objects which is more efficient than converting to Model Instances first before mapping them to just the values you want.

```
const results = await Model.findAll({
  attributes: ['value'],
  where: {
    code: { [Op.like]: 'images_default_droplet_%' },
    is_published: 1
  },
  raw: true, // return array of plain JSON objects
});

// 'datas' is an array of ["data","data","data"...]
const datas = results.map((result) => result.value);
```